# How to add users first name to templated responses in ServiceNow

Tags: javascript, servicenow, glidejs

I've created various templates for ticket responses in ServiceNow, but I'd like to personalise these by including info such as the users first name. e.g. "Hi Joe, Have you tried the following..."

I've tried adding the following into the Additional Comments field of the templates, but when applying the template they show the actual code to the users rather than populating their first name:

"Hi gs.getUser().getFirstName();
Have you tried the following..."

Is it possible to add such code into the Additional Comments field of ServiceNow?  If so, do I need to include it inside of certain symbols like <></> or similar?

It seems this should be a simple task, but after multiple searches of ServiceNow help guides, websites and forums and I'm still drawing a blank on this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.